# How to add GRUBs advanced options to Grub 2's landing page?

Tags: debian, grub2, grub

After updating the kernel of my beloved debian machine, and running update-grub, the new kernel option only appears in the advanced options and not the main landing page.

In the /boot/grub/menu.lst file I didnt find how or where to edit the advanced options. 
...This question might be able to be addressed elsewhere than grub as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [grub-customizer](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-grub-customizer-4-0-6-on-debian-8-0-jessie/) !

You can then just select the option and move it out of the advanced options folder using the arrows at the top right hand corner. Then just make sure to hit save.

Grub-customizer is also a great tool to add custom menu entries and themes to grub2.